# Converting ext2 to ext4

Tags: linux, filesystems

I have a file-server with three disk's that are ext2 file-systems, is it possible to change/convert these to ext4 which have much improved characteristics, while data is on the disk's and without data-loss?

If so, how is that accomplished?

My system is Debian Wheezy, and I use lvm.

I've found [this](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-convert-ext3-to-ext4-file-system.html), but I don't know if it is relevant for ext2 to ext4, does this work for me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The process of going from `ext2` to `ext4` is similar to your linked article for 3->4. You need to enable the features using `tune2fs`. The difference between going from 3->4 and 2->4 is that you also need to enable the journal feature. The complete command is this:

```
tune2fs -O extents,uninit_bg,dir_index,has_journal /dev/sdxx
```

You should `fsck` the filesystem after making the changes. As with any filesystem or disk changes, you should ensure you have a reliable backup before making the change.

Answer (score 1):

I am going to disagree with jordanm on two points.

Enabling the journal is a little more complicated than he presents, but there is a plethora of discussions and tutorials available.

The actions needed to convert an ext2 filesystem to ext3 or ext4 are as follows: do nothing. ext4 is a proper superset of ext3 which is a proper superset of ext2, there all ext2 filesystems are already ext4 file systems in addition to being ext3 as well. enabling any feature not supported by ext2 will however make it solely ext3/4, and indeed it is possible and sometimes useful to have an ext4 filesystem without a journal.